# Improving np.fromfuction performance in terms

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a big array for a high `dim` in `y_shift = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: (i)>>j, ((2**dim), dim), dtype=np.uint32)`. For example dim=32. I have two questions

1.- How to improve the speed in term of time

2.- How to avoid the message for dim=32 `zsh: killed     python3`

EDIT::
Alternative you can consider to use uint8 instead of uint32

`y_shift = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: (1&(i)>>j), ((2**dim), dim), dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: Is it necessary to write all this to memory? Have you looked into using generators?

Comment: I presume ´zsh: killed     python3´ appears because you run out of memory

Comment: @sehan2 I just edited the question, but even with that I trying `np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: 1&((i)>>j), ((2**dim), dim), dtype=np.uint8)` I get the same error

Comment: well do you have more than 137GB of memory? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282**32+*+32%29+byte+to+gigabyte

Comment: You're unlikely to be able to allocate a `(2**32, 32)` shaped array. That's 1/2TiB.

Comment: @sehan2. You forgot to multiply by 4 to account for the uint32 dtype

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes I know, I presumed he would update his question as in the comment and use uint8

Comment: numpy arrays can't have more than 32 dimensions.  That's hard coded.  Something is wrong if you hit that limit.

Comment: @hpaulj. It's 2D. The shape is just nonsense

Comment: @sehan2. His formula is specifically designed for `uint32`

Comment: @MadPhysicist ah ok, well then of cause he needs even more than 500GB... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282**32+*+32+*+4%29+byte+to+gigabyte

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

You get the error `zsh: killed     python3` because you run out of memory.

If you want to run the code you initially proposed:

```
dim =32
y_shift = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: (i)>>j, ((2**dim), dim), dtype=np.uint32)
```

You would need more than 500GB of memory, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282**32%20*%2032%20*%204%29%20byte%20to%20gigabyte).

I would recommend thinking of alternatives and avoid trying to save the entire array to memory.

Comment: thanks, even if use the alternative one? that is y_shift = np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: 1&((i)>>j), ((2**dim), dim), dtype=np.uint32)?

Comment: Checking if a binary value is even or odd does not change the memory consumption in your case I guess. Because you still write your result into 4 bytes of memory.

Comment: No matter how fast your function is or how small your dtype, the `2**dim` part scales terribly. With every extra dimension (`dim+=1`), you more than DOUBLE the size of the array (double the memory usage and double the times the function needs to run).

Answer (score 0):

`fromfunction` just does 2 things:

```
args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
return function(*args, **kwargs)
```

It makes the `indices` array

```
In [247]: args = np.indices(((2**4),4))
In [248]: args.shape
Out[248]: (2, 16, 4)
```

and it passes that array to your function

```
In [249]: args[0]>>args[1]
Out[249]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  1,  0,  0],
       ...
       [14,  7,  3,  1],
       [15,  7,  3,  1]])
```

With dim=32:

```
In [250]: ((2**32),32)
Out[250]: (4294967296, 32)
```

the resulting `args` array will be `(2, 4294967296, 32)`.  There's no way around that in terms of speed or memory use.